# Sequelize `findOne` working was not as expected

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js, next.js

I ran into a problem that I have not been able to solve for a week ...

When I pass the user's email to a query to the database, sequelize seems to do everything right and executes this query, it returns data from the table with the found result, but the result of executing the `findOne` function is not a model, why did this happen and how can I fix it?

```js
const email = 'email@example.com'
const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email }})

console.log(user.password) // undefined
```

Here is the model, service and database connection

***Model***

```js
import { DataTypes, Model } from "sequelize"
import { connection } from "./database"

class User extends Model {
  readonly id: number
  readonly email: string
  password: string
  username: string
  readonly createdAt: Date
  readonly updatedAt: Date
}

User.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize: connection,
    modelName: "users",
    createdAt: "created_at",
    updatedAt: "updated_at",
  }
)

export default User
```

***Service***

```js
export async function loginUser(email: string, password: string):  Promise<ServiceResponse<string>> {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email } })
    if (!user) {
      throw Error("User not found")
    }

    if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
      throw Error("User not found or password did not match")
    }

    const { password: _, ...payload } = user.toJSON()
    const token = jwt.sign(payload, environment.jwt)

    return { success: true, content: token }
  } catch (error) {
    return { success: false, error: error.message }
  }
}
```

***Database connection***

```js
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize"
import { environment } from "../environment"

export const connection = new Sequelize(environment.database, {
  dialect: "postgres",
  logging: console.log,
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  },
})
```

Here is log

```
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "email", "password", "username", "created_at", "updated_at" FROM "users" AS "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'email@example.com';
users {
  dataValues: {
    id: 9,
    email: 'email@example.com',
    password: '$2b$10$s0HFL9eBbcp3GcGkB9cDZuSiCjOEgfQB5lZLxhxXraRfvRF6voDfW',
    username: null,
    created_at: 2020-11-16T13:09:30.631Z,
    updated_at: 2020-11-16T13:09:30.631Z
  },
  _previousDataValues: {
    id: 9,
    email: 'email@example.com',
    password: '$2b$10$s0HFL9eBbcp3GcGkB9cDZuSiCjOEgfQB5lZLxhxXraRfvRF6voDfW',
    username: null,
    created_at: 2020-11-16T13:09:30.631Z,
    updated_at: 2020-11-16T13:09:30.631Z
  },
  _changed: Set(0) {},
  _options: {
    isNewRecord: false,
    _schema: null,
    _schemaDelimiter: '',
    raw: true,
    attributes: [
      'id',
      'email',
      'password',
      'username',
      'created_at',
      'updated_at'
    ]
  },
  isNewRecord: false,
  id: undefined,
  email: undefined,
  password: undefined,
  username: undefined,
  createdAt: undefined,
  updatedAt: undefined
}
```

Used stack `NextJS, Sequelize, PostgreSQL`

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, the answer is `Model.get({ plain: true })` before manipulating with received data.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your user object is it also undefined?

Try to do `user.dataValues.password` to get password.
Or you can add `raw: true` like this
`const user = await User.findOne({ raw:true, where: { email }})`.Sequelize will return only data not the model instance. So you can use `user.password`

Answer (score 1):

Model instances operate with the concept of a `dataValues` property, which stores the actual values represented by the instance.
As you can see in your printout under `dataValues` you have your model:

```
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "email", "password", "username", "created_at", "updated_at" FROM "users" AS "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'email@example.com';
users {
  dataValues: {
    id: 9,
    email: 'email@example.com',
    password: '$2b$10$s0HFL9eBbcp3GcGkB9cDZuSiCjOEgfQB5lZLxhxXraRfvRF6voDfW',
    username: null,
    created_at: 2020-11-16T13:09:30.631Z,
    updated_at: 2020-11-16T13:09:30.631Z
  },
  _previousDataValues: {
      (...)
```

To get data from this `dataValues` field you can use `get` method.
Also `findOne` return a promise.

So taking it together, in your case I think this should work

```
const email = 'email@example.com'
User.findOne({ where: { email }}).then(data => {
    console.log(data.get('password')
});
```

Take a look at [Sequelize Model documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html)

Answer (score 0):

By default, Sequelize returns an instance of the model, which may contain some extra properties and methods specific to Sequelize models.
To restrict it by doing so and in order to get only the specific model data you need to add **raw:true** , then you will be able to directly manipulate the model object. I'm attaching an example that how it would be worked.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4HbX.png)